# How to retrieve contents of a Google Docs Document using the Google API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am creating a news aggregator using python and now I need to retrieve the contents of a Google doc document. I googled around only to find info on how to retrieve data from google sheets.

I tried `document.get` but I couldn't understand

Answer (score 0):

have you tried following the steps laid out in this documentation https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python ?

Comment: It has no method to retrieve the contents

Comment: I could see a json representation of the Google doc but there is no specific method listed there