# How to Accept style suggestions of a google doc with Google Doc API?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

As title, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052008/how-to-retrieve-all-suggestion-accepted-content-of-a-document-on-google-doc-thro) I already know how to retrieve all-suggestion-accepted content of a document. Now I also want to retrieve the "style suggestion" of the content of the document. I've referred to the second half part of [this guideline](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/suggestions), but still have no clue about it. Below is the snippet I have as yet.

```
function get_all_suggestion_accepted()
{
  
  var doc_id = 'My doc ID';
  SUGGEST_MODE = 'PREVIEW_SUGGESTIONS_ACCEPTED'
  suggestions = Docs.Documents.get(doc_id, {
    'suggestionsViewMode': SUGGEST_MODE,
    "textStyleSuggestionState": { "underlineSuggested": true, }
  });

  var new_content = '';
  
  suggestions.body.content.forEach(obj => {
    if(obj.paragraph)
      obj.paragraph.elements.forEach(element => {
        new_content += element.textRun.content;
      });
  });
  
   console.log(new_content); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, **accepting/rejecting** suggestions via **Google Docs API** is not possible.

To retrieve the style suggestion, you need to access the `textRun` of each paragraph element and check if `suggestedTextStyleChanges` exists.

**Example:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var suggestions = Docs.Documents.get("doc id");
  suggestions.body.content.forEach(obj => {
    if(obj.paragraph)
      obj.paragraph.elements.forEach(element => {
        if(element.textRun.suggestedTextStyleChanges){
          Logger.log(element.textRun.content);
          Logger.log(element.textRun.suggestedTextStyleChanges);
        }
      });
  });
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Edit

In your code, you added `"textStyleSuggestionState": { "underlineSuggested": true, }`, but `Docs.get` method only accepts `suggestionsViewMode` as **Query Parameter** and the values you can input are:

> **DEFAULT_FOR_CURRENT_ACCESS** - The SuggestionsViewMode applied to the
> returned document depends on the user's current access level. If the
> user only has view access, PREVIEW_WITHOUT_SUGGESTIONS is applied.
> Otherwise, SUGGESTIONS_INLINE is applied. This is the default
> suggestions view mode.
>
> **SUGGESTIONS_INLINE**     The returned document has suggestions inline.
> Suggested changes will be differentiated from base content within the
> document.
>
> Requests to retrieve a document using this mode will return a 403
> error if the user does not have permission to view suggested changes.
>
> **PREVIEW_SUGGESTIONS_ACCEPTED**   The returned document is a preview with
> all suggested changes accepted.
>
> Requests to retrieve a document using this mode will return a 403
> error if the user does not have permission to view suggested changes.
>
> **PREVIEW_WITHOUT_SUGGESTIONS**   The returned document is a preview with
> all suggested changes rejected if there are any suggestions in the
> document.

The correct way to find all the `underlineSuggested: true` is by traversing it in the Response body and use `SUGGESTIONS_INLINE` as `suggestionsViewMode`.

**Example:**

**Document:**

[image]

This code will print the string that has underline suggestion:

```
function get_all_suggestion_accepted() {
  var suggestions = Docs.Documents.get("11Tx4uvv5yN_TplT4TIUyEWTZ6bUMTGaensYT20EZ4r0");
  suggestions.body.content.forEach(obj => {
    if(obj.paragraph)
      obj.paragraph.elements.forEach(element => {
        if(element.textRun.suggestedTextStyleChanges){
          var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element.textRun.suggestedTextStyleChanges));
          if(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].textStyleSuggestionState.underlineSuggested){
            Logger.log(element.textRun.content);
          }
        }
      });
  });
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note**: If you want to view all the suggestions, you have to use  `SUGGESTIONS_INLINE` in the `textStyleSuggestionState` query parameter or remove it as `SUGGESTIONS_INLINE` is the default view if you have access to the document. Also, when you use `PREVIEW_SUGGESTIONS_ACCEPTED` you won't see any suggestions in the object as it returns a preview of the document with all the suggestions accepted.

### Further Reading

- [SuggestedTextStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#suggestedtextstyle)
- [Javascript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
- [HTTP Request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question is that in [this guideline](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/suggestions), I can retrieve all-suggestion-accepted content such as insertion and deletion. Therefore, can I retrieve the same things but with style-suggestion in the same way?

Comment: @Steven.Y - Do you mean you can add `'suggestionsViewMode': SUGGEST_MODE,
    "textStyleSuggestionState": { "underlineSuggested": true, }` to your code and still able to retrieve the style suggestion?

Comment: Yes this is what I want. If not is there any other plausible way to achieve this?

Comment: @Steven.Y - I updated my answer. Let me know if you still have question.